# No-nonsense iOS camera app that allows varying picture filesize (width/height)

Tags: ios, camera

The default iOS camera app doesn't have a picture filesize menu (all photos are taken at the maximum size). This takes up much more space than needed.

I'm looking for a camera app with the specifications listed:

- Select photo size in pixel width/height
- Preferably take photo and video from the app with variable pixel width/height.
- Preferably free, although a small 1-time payment is OK
- No automatic uploading of anything to the internet (including "automatic backup" or "sync" services). No forced cloud service integration. I'd prefer a camera app that doesn't connect to the internet or cloud service under any circumstances.
- Obviously, no spyware. The app should only record when instructed to, and never from the background (when it isn't the active app)
- No microtransactions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand all your requirements but there is a free app, Image Size, which allows you to easily resize images on your ios device. It has several units, including pixels and inches, that you can use for resizing. This app is available at the app store. I don't think it works on video so maybe this isn't best. You might go the 2 app route where one app converts video to still images and then this app to resize them.

Comment: I'd like to take pictures at a given size instead of manually going through my photo library and resizing them.

Comment: ok. Sorry. You may not be able to do that but good luck.